# Youtube V3 API new subscription videos script

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

so I am new to programming and need to use the Youtube V3 to get new subscription videos of a user. After some research I found out that it's not possible to directly get it - there is no one api call that gives you it. I found a third party solution online but I am having trouble implementing it. Here is the solution : https://github.com/ali1234/ytsubs . 
I have to put in the YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY and the developer notes that

```
 # YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY="<your_secret_key>" ./ytsubs.py <username> <output RSS file>
 baseurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3'
 my_key = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY')
 # check for missing inputs
 if not my_key:
    print "YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY variable missing."
    sys.exit(-1)
```

I tried adding my key in different formats but I keep getting the variable missing error. I think it's because I am not too familiar with python and it's environment variable. What format should I put it in? 
I tried:

```
my_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY' + ' ./views.py username output.rss')
my_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY' , ' ./views.py username output.rss')
my_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY ./views.py' + ' username output.rss')
```

and many other formats but they all give the missing key error. I am using the V3 api on google app engine.

I tried this as well:

```
os.environ['YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY'] = "SECRET_KEY", "username", "hi.rss";
my_key = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY');
```

and now I get : sys.argv len not >2 error

Comment: `YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY="<your_secret_key>" ./ytsubs.py <username> <output RSS file>` this should be given from terminal
not inside the script

Comment: isn't there any way to give it inside the script?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/yAu8QPByNu2BBNyzxY5w3
replace user_name with desired username;filename with a proper name

Comment: I tried that before, I get this error : http://pasteboard.co/WaWjrnc.png

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux

In your terminal

```
export 'YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY'=yourkey
```

and run your python script.

If you are from windows
Check this [`link`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_environmnt_addchange_variable.mspx?mfr=true) and add the 
`new variable name='YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY' and value=yourkey`.

If you want to do this on fly in your python script then

```
os.environ['YOUTUBE_SERVER_API_KEY'] = "yourkey"
```

Comment: how would I do it on the fly when the app would be deployed - I can't always be using the terminal

Comment: it was able to get the key now but the sys.agrv length is apparently only one - when I think it should be 3 - key - username - rss file name

Comment: the whole script is based on getting value in this form sys.argv[0] or sys.argv[1]. I know sys.argv is a lis of the command line arguments and I am not trying to use the command line. When I change the script to not use sys.argv[] but rather global variable I get, "viewDoesNotExist" error. So yeah, I don't know what to do here.

Comment: use a text editor like sublimetext or notepad++;find and replace all instances of sys.argv[1] with some global variable name say user_name

Comment: I already tried that - when I do that it give "viewDoesNotExist" error